# Which model fit best colinear indepent variables?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, multicollinearity

I have one dependent variable ($y$) and $200$ linear independent variables. However, some of them are related (exists multicollinearity). Therefore, I can't use multivariable linear regression. I tried using ridge regression but I'm facing the problem that my $R^2 = 10\%$.

My y variable represents the concentration of an element:

$y =[0,013; 0.450;0.556; 1.356;2,222]$ (not binary)

There are any other useful model that could help?

Comment: Did you pick the regularisation parameter of ridge by cross validation? If you did the $R^2$ value you get isn't higher for potentially two reasons: A linear additive function of the variables is a good approximation of how they predict the mean of $y$ . 10% better than its unconditional mean is the signal value of those variables, and no model will do much better. Alternatively, linear additive is a poor approximation. To check that, you can fit decision tree based models and see whether you get  better predictions. Like ridge, they can also deal with variables being highly correlated.

Comment: Thank you @CloseToC. I will try it!